# Binomial distribution approaches to Poisson or Normal?

Tags: probability-distributions, normal-distribution, poisson-distribution, binomial-distribution

I'm reading two books and they say differently.

In a binomial distribution $X \sim \text{Bin}(n,p)$, if $n \to +\infty$, $X$ approaches to Poisson distribution $\text{Po}(np)$.

The other book says $X$ approaches to normal distribution $\text{N}(np,np(1-p))$.

I'm confused.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Either the two books are sloppy or you're not reading precisely.

- If $n\to\infty$ and $p\to0$ while $np$ approaches some positive number $\lambda,$ then the binomial distribution approaches a Poisson distribution with expected value $\lambda.$
- If $n\to\infty$ as $p$ stays fixed, and $X\sim\operatorname{Binomial}(n,p)$ then the distribution of $(X-np)/\sqrt{np(1-p)}$ approaches the standard normal distribution, i.e. the normal distribution with expected value $0$ and standard deviation $1.$

It is sloppy to say something approaches something depending on $n$ as $n\to\infty,$ unless it is precisely defined and not meant literally. Thus the statement that something approaches $\operatorname{Binomial}(np, np(1-p))$ as $n\to\infty$ is not to be taken literally, but rather it means what is stated in the second bullet point above, where the limit, the standard normal distribution, does not depend on $n.$ In the first bullet point above, the statement that something approaches $\operatorname{Poisson}(np)$ can make sense only because $np$ does not depend on $n,$ that is, what is considered is a limit as $n\to\infty$ and $p\to0$ which $np$ remains fixed.

Comment: It becomes very clear. Thanks. I think we could say N(np,np(1-p)) then. Don't know why you modified to standard normal instead of normal.

Comment: Because it is never actually $N(np,np(1-p))$. If $X$ is binomially distributed, then $X$ can only take finitely many values (each with positive probability). The normal distribution has support over uncountably many values (the real line), each with 0 probability.

Comment: @DanielXiang : The pointwise limit of the sequence of c.d.f.s is the c.d.f. of the standard normal distribution. $\qquad$

Comment: Right. I was just making the point that the random variable is never distributed $N(np,np(1-p))$ for any finite $n$, which motivates the reason for writing $(X-np)/\sqrt{np(1-p)} \implies N(0,1)$ as opposed to $X \implies N(np,np(1-p))$.

Comment: As far as I can tell, $(X-np)/\sqrt{np(1-p)}$ is never distributed as $N(0,1)$ either. What's the difference?

Comment: @kevinkayaks : Its distribution can be made as close as desired to standard normal by making $n$ big enough while $p$ stays fixed.